# R vectorised alternatives to For loops involving operations with non-numericals (dataframe rebuilding)

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, dataframe, vectorization

Here is my problem:

Suppose I have a dataframe showing some observations of certain items. These observations contain *numeric* values as well as some *character* properties. It goes like this:

```
items <- c("item1","item1","item1","item2","item2","item3")
proptyA <- c("prop1", "prop1", "prop1", "prop2", "prop2", "prop2")
proptyB <- c("prop11", "prop11", "prop11", "prop11", "prop11", "prop12")
proptyC <- c("prop22", "prop22", "prop22", "prop22", "prop22", "prop22")
values <- c(1:6)

rawDF <- data.frame(items, proptyA, proptyB, proptyC, values, stringsAsFactors = F)

  items proptyA proptyB proptyC values
1 item1   prop1  prop11  prop22      1
2 item1   prop1  prop11  prop22      2
3 item1   prop1  prop11  prop22      3
4 item2   prop2  prop11  prop22      4
5 item2   prop2  prop11  prop22      5
6 item3   prop2  prop12  prop22      6
```

I am looking for a way to rebuild the dataframe to be centered around 'Items' and not the current observations. The resulting dataframe would present some aggregation of values (e.g. sum). No real 'aggregation' of properties need taking place since each item only has one unique property of each type.

The resulting dataframe should look like:

```
  items proptyA proptyB proptyC values
1 item1   prop1  prop11  prop22      6
2 item2   prop2  prop11  prop22      9
3 item3   prop2  prop12  prop22      6
```

Sadly I do not see how to get to this result without resorting to Loops. Surely `tapply(rawDF$values, rawDF$items, sum)` sorts the *numerical* bit out, but what about *characters* in properties.

Loops, however, are not an option for me, due to the size of the real dataset I am working with.

I will appreciate any help on this. Absolutely fine with using additional packages etc. although would prefer a base R solution if there is one.

Thank you!

Comment: Does `aggregate(rawDF$values, by=rawDF[, c("items", "proptyA", "proptyB", "proptyC")], sum)` give you the results you want?

Comment: I think `items` needs to be added to the columns in `by`, but otherwise the output from your code matches expected output from OP.

Comment: Thanks, just realized that and edited my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `aggregate`

```
aggregate(rawDF$values, by=rawDF[, c("items", "proptyA", "proptyB", "proptyC")], sum)

  items proptyA proptyB proptyC x
1 item1   prop1  prop11  prop22 6
2 item2   prop2  prop11  prop22 9
3 item3   prop2  prop12  prop22 6
```

**Edit**:  using the formula class

```
aggregate(values~., rawDF, sum)

  items proptyA proptyB proptyC values
1 item1   prop1  prop11  prop22      6
2 item2   prop2  prop11  prop22      9
3 item3   prop2  prop12  prop22      6
```